# Not able to load file formats other than MATLAB files in Octave

Tags: octave

Octave can easily load MATLAB files, for example `load('names.m')`. But while trying to load file formats other than MATLAB file format like `load('names.txt')` I am getting an error:

> error: load: unable to determine file format of 'names.txt'

[image: Error-not able to find the text file]

Comment: "not able to find the text file" is very different from "unable to determine file format of 'names.txt'". Please be accurate when reporting error messages. You should always copy-paste the full error message into your question. Note that pictures of text are not very useful, some people cannot read them and they don't allow searching for those terms either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Octave supports matlab file formats . But to load text files use the following code in terminal `load('-ascii','names.txt');` This will load the text file without showing any error.

Comment: Nice one understanding what OP meant by "names.txt". I didn't even think it would be an ascii data file, I just thought "how do I open a text file for reading" ... xD

Comment: That's indeed true xd